# Yii2 fixtures + Codeception functional (rest) tests

Tags: rest, yii2, codeception, fixtures

As I understand reading Yii2 docs, fixtures used for unit tests only, but what I have to do if i need to test api?
If I extend cest from TestCase (yii\codeception), codeception assumes inherited methods as tests and ofc fails it.

[There's a discussion about some FixtureHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31873977/3322208) which I couldn't find at Yii2 repo.

Comment: didn't try writing tests for REST in Yii yet but I've seen codeception having built-in stuff for it. see http://codeception.com/docs/10-WebServices